# Mathematical Approximation for Quantum tunnelling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

After some long basic algebraic transformation the transmission coefficient $T$ for a matter wave  $\psi_1$ with wave vector $k_1 $ travelling with a wave vector $k_2$ through a wall of length $l$ and with a potential $V$ greater than the potential energy $E$ of the matter wave is found to be:

$$T = \dfrac{4\,{k_1}^2\,{k_2}^2}{\left({k_1}^2+{k_2}^2\right)^2\,\sinh^2{k_2\,l}+4\,{k_1}^2\,{k_2}^2} $$

My question concerns the following simplifications made:

First of it is being said: $\sinh^2(k_2\,l) = \left(\dfrac{e^{\textstyle k_2\,l}-e^{\textstyle -k_2\,l}}{2}\right)^2 \approx\dfrac{1}{4}e^{\textstyle 2\,k_2\,l}$. I'm okay with that, since $e^{\textstyle -k_2\,l}$ can be neglected for big $l$. It follows the transmission coefficient can be rewritten:

$$T = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{16}\left(\dfrac{k_1}{k_2}+\dfrac{k_2}{k_1}\right)^2\,e^{\textstyle 2\,k_2\,l}+1} $$

Now the point that I'm not grasping: it's being claimed for equally sized wave vectors $k_1$ and $k_2$ the Transmission coefficient simply becomes: $T = 16\,e^{\textstyle -2\,k_2\,l}$. It looks short and sharp but I don't see how the fraction can be cleared out. Also what does it mean physically the original matter wave $\psi_1$ maintains almost the same wave vector $k_1 \approx k_2$ when permeating the wall?

Comment: If you are OK with $e^{-k_2l}\ll 1$, then it's the same as saying $e^{2k_2l}\gg 1$, so you can drop the constant $1$ in the denominator. Then for $k_1=k_2$, you should find $T=4e^{-2k_2l}$.

Comment: Exactly. I'd also expect this result but for some reason the  factor was chosen to be $T = 16\cdots $. I guess a typing error. What's your physical interpretation of same order wave vectors?